# Prevent CSS3 rotation second time

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to do this? I have an image which rotates to a grey area. This is fine. What I want is, that it says on the grey area if I click again on the area. What is the best way to do this?

Here you have an example of what I have:

**http://jsfiddle.net/YaUPs/**

CSS:

```
  .f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin:10px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index : 1;
    float:left;
  }
  .f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
  }
 .f1_card {
     width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
  }
  .f1_container.active .f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
  }
  .face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
  }
   body{width:2000px}
```

Comment: You want to get grey area if click on grey area? Isnt?

Comment: Can't you just do an `addClass` on the first click and leave it instead of doing `toggleClass`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your JS with:

```
$('.f1_container').one('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The `one` function executes the event only once per element.

Furthermore, I've changed your `toggleClass` to a simple `addClass`, either of these changes should be sufficient by itself, however, theres no need for a toggle here.

http://jsfiddle.net/YaUPs/392/

Answer (score 0):

You want to get grey area if click on grey area? Isnt? If yes below It will help

```
$('.f1_container').click(function() {
 $(this).addClass('active');
});
```